# Func not calling second method despite awaiting

Tags: c#, async-await

I am wondering why my console line in Class B is not printed in below implementation.
its working fine if I put the console out of the `Task.Run` call. I understand that they run on a separate thread but since I am awaiting both, I thought I will see the console Statements. what am I missing here.

```
class Program
    {
        static readonly IMyInterface myInterfaceA = new A();
        static readonly IMyInterface myInterfaceB = new B();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var jk = GetRes(async (imy) => await imy.GetUser());
        }

         async static Task GetRes(Func<IMyInterface, Task<User>> func)
        {
             await func(myInterfaceA);
             await func(myInterfaceB);
        }
    }

    interface IMyInterface
    {
        Task<User> GetUser();
    }

    class A : IMyInterface
    {
        public async Task<User> GetUser()
        {
            return await Task.Run(()=>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"GetUser in Class A");
                return new User();
            });
        }
    }

    class B : IMyInterface
    {
        public async Task<User> GetUser()
        {
            return await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"GetUser in Class B");
                return new User();
            });
        }
    }

public class User
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You never await `jk`, so `Main()` exits early. At this point you have no guarantee about what will have the time to execute before the process ends.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await GetRes(async (imy) => await imy.GetUser());
}
```

Comment: ohh. I missed that. my bad :( totally dumb